# Can't slugify routed url's in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to slugify some routed url's. I followed this [article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCore22ParameterTransformersForCleanURLGenerationAndSlugsInRazorPagesOrMVC.aspx), but I can't replicate the result. When setting a breakpoint in  TransformOutbound() it never hits, so I guess the transformer never gets called for some reason.

**SlugifyParameterTransformer**:

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        string result = default;

        if (!value.IsNull())
        {
            result = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Startup**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLCAssets(opt => 
        {
            opt.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
        });
}
```

**AddLCAssets**:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddLCAssets(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MvcOptions> options = default)
{
    if (options != default)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(Const.DefaultCompatibilityVersion);
    }
    else
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(Const.DefaultCompatibilityVersion);
    }

    return services;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your `SlugifyParameterTransformer` class should be as follows:

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        // Slugify value
        return value == null ? null : Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
    }
}
```

Then in the `Startup.ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
services.AddRouting(option =>
{
    option.ConstraintMap["slugify"] = typeof(SlugifyParameterTransformer);
    option.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

Then your route configuration in `Startup.Configure` should be as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
```

The above settings will make `/Employee/EmployeeDetails/1` route to `/employee/employee-details/1`